# Icon in Spotfire fades but does not disappear

Tags: javascript, ironpython, tibco, spotfire

I have a listbox in Spotfire with countries in it.  The listbox includes (None) as a selection option.  When a country is selected in the listbox the country's name and a star icon appears in another test panel.  After that, if (None) is selected, the country' name disappears but the star only fades out.  I need it to disappear just as the text does.

Here's an example:

USA is selected
[image: country selected][image: country output]

then None is selected
[image: none selected][image: none output]

Here is the javascript I have in the panel for the output.  The intention is to not display the icon if None is selected.

```js
$("#b67963fdb4724d11b744affb05048a23").on('change',function(){
 $("#b67963fdb4724d11b744affb05048a23 option:selected").text()=="None"?
 document.getElementById($("#9bf3680df22140b9955b39c8ba6cfff8")).style.display = "hidden" :
 document.getElementById($("#9bf3680df22140b9955b39c8ba6cfff8")).style.display = "visible"
})
```

Here's the icon properties:

[image]

How do I make the icon disappear if no country is selected?

Answer (score 3):

the faded out behavior happens when there is a null value, but some other rule was matched before the selection changed. this behavior is probably a bug.

you can see the behavior you want if you select a country that doesn't begin with R, A, U, or C; selecting `KOREA`, for example, would make the icon disappear because there is no rule that covers `Starts with K`, and the value is not null. selecting `(None)` next would correctly display no icon.

you can change the null output using the `SN()` function ("SubstituteNull"). by providing a value that is both NOT NULL *and* not matched by any rule, the icon won't show. your formula would be:

```
SN(UniqueConcatenate([Country]), '_')
```

choose any character you like; it doesn't have to be `_`, but it should match the datatype of the column.

this behavior is the same for **Icon** columns in a Graphical Table. this workaround applies as of Spotfire 7.6.

Comment: Great explanation!

Comment: Hey no problem! Don't forget to accept the answer as correct since it helped you out :)